# Laravel-5 and Multitenancy database setup

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm starting to develop an SaaS application and I have created my database structure.  I'm planning to create a middleware file which handles the database connection for that request.  Within this middleware file I want to create a model which will always select only rows from any table that corresponds to the current connection `cust_id` (foreign key).

For example:

```
$Customers->where('cust_id', $cust_id)->first();
```

How can I do this without having to specify `where('cust_id', $cust_id)` in every select statement?

Comment: If you were using Eloquent models you could simply achieve that using global query scopes. When working directly witn DB facade it will be much harder, as it offers no easy way to plug in such automated behaviour like you describe. Let me know if using Eloquent instead of DB is possible in your case and I'll post an example - we've done something pretty similar in my current project.

Comment: Yes, sorry I will be using Eloquent models anyway, I will update my question now.

Comment: And what do you mean by "current connection cust_id"? How should that multitenancy work? I understand that it's one database and you want to automatically filter only the records where cust_id is equal to some specific value -- is that correct?

Comment: Yes, well basically every table has a `cust_id` field.  I only ever want to select rows where `cust_id` is equal to the current user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve that using **Eloquent's global query scopes** in your models. You can read more about them here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes

First, you need to define the **Multitenant** scope class, that will update all the queries that run and add the constraint on **cust_id** field:

```
class MultitenantScope implements ScopeInterface
{
  public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
  {
    if (Auth::id()) {
      $builder->whereCustId(Auth::id()); 
    } else {
      $model = $builder->getModel();
      // apply a constraint that will never be true
      // so that no records are fetched for unauthorized users
      $builder->whereNull($model->getKeyName()); 
    }
 }

  public function remove(Builder $builder, Model $model)
  {
    $query = $builder->getQuery();
    $query->wheres = collect($query->wheres)->reject(function ($where) {
      return ($where['column'] == 'cust_id');
    })->values()->all();
  }  
}
```

Then you need a **trait** that you will add to the models that need to be filtered:

```
trait MultitenantTrait
{
  public static function bootMultitenantTrait()
  {
    static::addGlobalScope(new MultitenantScope());
  }

  public static function allTenants()
  {
    return (new static())->newQueryWithoutScope(new MultitenantScope());
  }
}
```

The last piece is adding the **MultitenantTrait** to your model:

```
class SomeModel extends Eloquent {
  use MultitenantTrait;
}
```

Now, every time you do any query using Eloquent's model methods, the **cust_id** constraint will be applied to the query and only models that belong to given **cust_id** will be available.

If for some reason you'll need to access all objects, you can use **allTenants()** method to run the query without the additional constraint:

```
$allRows = SomeModel::allTenants()->get();
```

Please keep in mind that I haven't tested that exact code, so let me know if you see any issues and I'll be more than happy to get that working for you :)

Comment: This is how I would have solved the problem as well.. +1 Nice and elaborative answer...

Comment: I managed to get this working, the only problem I am having is that because I have some joins on certain queries, I am getting this error: `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'cust_id' in where clause is ambiguous`.  Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Yes, a simple one. You need to prefix your column name with table name. Instead of "$builder->whereCustId(Auth::id()); " do "$builder->where('some_table.cust_id', '=', Auth::id());". You might also prefix it in the place where you define the join.